# calculating $a^b \!\mod c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, faq

What is the fastest way (general method) to calculate the quantity $a^b \!\mod c$? For example $a=2205$, $b=23$, $c=4891$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's assume that `a,b,c` referred to here are positive integers, as in your example.

For a specific exponent `b`, there may be a faster (shorter) method of computing `a^b` than binary exponentiation.  Knuth has a discussion of the phenomenon in Art of Computer Programming Vol. 2 (Semi-numerical Algorithms), Sec. 4.6.3 and the index term "addition chains".  He cites `b=15` as the smallest case where binary exponentiation is not optimal, in that it requires six multiplication but `a^3` can be computed in two multiplications, and then `(a^3)^5` in three more for a total of five multiplications.

For the specific exponent `b=23` the parsimonious addition chain involves the exponents (above `1`) `2,3,5,10,13`, at which point `a^23 = (a^10)*(a^13)`, for a total of six multiplications.  Binary exponentiation for `b=23` requires seven multiplications.

Another approach that can produce faster results when `b` is large (not in your example) depends on knowing something about the base `a` and modulus `c`.  Recall from Euler's generalization of Fermat's Little Thm. that if `a,c` are coprime, then `a^d = 1 mod c` for `d` the Euler `phi` function of `c` (the number of positive integers less than `c` and coprime to it).  In particular if `c` is a prime, then by Fermat's Little Thm. either `c` divides `a` and `a^b = 0 mod c` or else `a^b = a^e mod c` where `e = b mod (c-1)` since `phi(c) = c-1` for a prime `c`.

If the base `a` and modulus `c` are not coprime, then it might be advantageous to factor `a` into its greatest common factor with `c` and its largest factor that is coprime to `c`.

Also it might be advantageous if `c` is not prime to factor it into prime powers and do separate exponentiations for each such factor, piecing them back together via the Chinese Remainder Thm.  In your example `c = 4891 = 67*73`, so you might compute `a^b mod 67` and `a^b mod 73` and combine those results to get `a^b mod c`.  This is especially helpful if you are limited in the precision of integer arithmetic you can do.

Answer (score 3):

The [square-and-multiply algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is generally the fastest way to do modular exponentiation.

Answer (score 2):

The [Russian peasant's method](https://web.archive.org/web/20180101093529/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.peasant.html) is pretty straightforward for computing $a^b\bmod m$:

```
c=a;d=b;r=1;
while d≠0
if d is odd then r=(cr) mod m;
d=d div 2; \\ integer division; one usually right-shifts bits in practice
c=c^2 mod m;
endwhile
r
```

Comment: This is just the square-and-multiply algorithm...

Answer (score 1):

One common way of fast exponentiation, either in modular arithmetic or in general, is [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Further_application). Here is [the section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Further_applications) where they talk specifically about $a^b\bmod c$.

Answer (score 1):

Generally [repeated squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) works well. It deserves to be better known that this arises simply from writing the exponent in binary radix in Horner polynomial form, i.e. $\rm\ d_0 + x\ (d_1 + x\ (d_2\ +\:\cdots))\:.\ $ Below is an example of computing $\rm\ a^{101}\ $ by repeated squaring. Note that the repeated square form arises simply from performing various substitutions into the binary polynomial Horner form  namely $\rm\ 1\to a,\ \ 0\to 1,\ \ (x)\:2\to (x)^2\ $ into $101_{10} = 1100101_2\ $ expanded into Horner form, viz.
[image]