# Solve $(5+2\sqrt{6})^{\frac{x}{2}} + ( 5-2\sqrt{6})^{\frac{x}{2}} = 10$

Tags: real-analysis, radicals

I wish to solve the equation
$$(5+2\sqrt{6})^{\frac{x}{2}} + ( 5-2\sqrt{6})^{\frac{x}{2}} = 10$$

I tried factorizing until I reached
$(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^x + (\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})^x = 10$ 
But from there I don't know what to do any help would be welcome 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't it quite clear what the answer should be? Try some small natural numbers in the initial equation you are given. This is a good lesson in inspecting the problem _before_ you run into a bunch of algebra!

Comment: I know it's 2 but that's not what I want thanks

Comment: I don't understand - what do you want then?

Comment: Get a formal way of arriving at the answer

Comment: @arsenestein `I know it's 2` $x=-2$ is  a solution as well.

Comment: @JohnDoe: Solving an equation requires **proving rigorously** what exactly are the solutions. Just finding one is nowhere near enough, but sometimes finding one can be an important part of the solution. For example one can use real analysis to solve $x^2 = 2^x$ where $x$ is a positive real.

Comment: @user21820 I agree that that is true, but what can be done is to find solutions and then prove no more solutions exist (as done by Alex's answer). I didn't spot the method of Dylan's answer myself, however.

Comment: @JohnDoe: That's what I said in my comment, so I don't understand your earlier comment in response to the asker, who obviously doesn't just want the answer but wants a proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve $(5-2\sqrt6)^n + (5+2\sqrt6)^n = 98$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28157/how-to-solve-5-2-sqrt6n-52-sqrt6n-98)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2} > 0$, your equation should simplify to

$$ (\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2})^x + (\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2})^x = 10 $$

Also note that
$$ \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}} $$

Let $t = (\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^x$, then

$$ t + \frac{1}{t} = 10 $$
$$ t^2 - 10t + 1 = 0 $$

which gives $t = 5 \pm 2\sqrt{6}$

Therefore $x = \pm 2$

Comment: Okay thanks I've got it

Comment: If you're done, make sure to "tick" your favorite answer to close the question

Comment: your $\lambda^2 - 10 \lambda + 1 = 0$ also appears as a degree two linear recurrence for the values, once for even $x,$ once for odd $x$

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions: $x=2$ and $x=-2$.

We easily see that $x=2$ is a solution. There are no other solutions $x>0$ because the left-hand side is an increasing function on ${\mathbb R}^+$.
Indeed, noticing that $1/(5+2\sqrt{6})=5-2\sqrt{6}$, we then find that
$$
f(x) = (5+2√6)^{\frac{x}{2}} + ( 5-2√6)^{\frac{x}{2}}
$$
is an even function $(f(x)=a^x+a^{-x}=2\cosh(x\log a))$. So we have the second solution $x=-2$, and no other solutions for $x<0$ because $f(x)$ is decreasing on ${\mathbb R}^-$.

Comment: OK but isn't there a way of arriving at x=2?

Comment: This can be solved without using calculus

Comment: `left-hand side is an increasing function on R+` That could be elaborated some more, since it's not trivially obvious. The LHS is the sum of two terms with opposite monotonicity, $(5+2 \sqrt{6})^x$ is increasing while $(5-2 \sqrt{6})^x$ is *de*creasing.

Comment: @Alex Using calculus, you could write $f(x) = a^x + a^{-x}$ then argue that $f'(x) = (a^x-a^{-x}) \log(a)$ is strictly monotonic and has a zero at $x=0$, so it must keep the same sign on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\mathbb{R}^-$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks @dxiv. :)

Comment: Or just notice that $a^x+a^{-x}=2\cosh\xi$, where $\xi=x\log a$, and use properties of the $\cosh$ function.