# Can anybody tell me how to find the value of $\alpha$?

Tags: puzzle

I don't know how to find the value of $\alpha$:
$$(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^\alpha + (\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^\alpha = 10$$
I tried to simplify it to
$$(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^\alpha=5$$
then take the ($\ln$) of both sides
$$\ln{(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^\alpha} = \ln{5}$$
then $$\alpha\ln{(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})} = \ln{5}$$
then $$\alpha = \frac{\ln{5}}{\ln{(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})}}$$
is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, I’m voting to close this question because you show no work of your own. This is not a "do it for me" site. If you [edit] the question to tell us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help.

Comment: Did you try to divide by $2$ first?

Comment: I voted to reopen because you showed enough work. However, you completely solved your (strange but obvious) exercise, so I think this post can be deleted now. I don't think it can be useful to anyone.

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.  For a slightly more compact result, you could take $\log_5$ of both sides in place of the $\ln$ step, giving $\alpha=\frac 1{\log_5(\sqrt 3+\sqrt2)}$, but this is neither expected nor any better or worse than what you have done.

Comment: Is it possible that the equation be $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})^\alpha + (\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})^\alpha = 10$? then the answer will be very simple $\alpha = 2$

Comment: But if @Etemon's guess is right, your question is rather a duplicate of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2600381 which was itself a dupe of: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/78607 (and there are *two* solutions: $2$ and $-2$).