# How to simpify the way of calculating $(a^b \bmod c) \bmod d$?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

Right now I know the way to calculate $a^b \bmod c$ which is in the answer of the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26722/calculating-ab-mod-c).

Consider the case where $c$ is much larger than $d$. So, the result of $a^b \bmod c$ will be large compared with the final result.

Is there any way to get the final result without getting directly the result of $a^b \bmod c$ which is large?

Comment: I don't think so. By definition $(a^b \mod c) = a^b - k \cdot c$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and in general $(a^b - k_1 \cdot c) \not\equiv (a^b - k_2 \cdot c) \mod d$ for $k_1 \neq k_2$ (unless there is some hidden relation between $c$ and $d$). So before you continue with the $\mod d$-step, you need to find the right $k$ (or the right value $a^b - k \cdot c$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known solution to this problem. If there were, it would be in use all over the world in implementations of the RSA algorithm for smart cards.

If $d$ and $c$ have a factor in common, then you can use this to speed up the computation -- and in fact this is routinely done in smart cards when the RSA private key is known. But otherwise, you just have to compute $a^b \mod c$ and reduce the result modulo $d$.