# modulo of series summation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, summation

I have trouble with computing modulo.
First, I have a summation of series like this:
$$1+3^2+3^4+\cdots+3^n$$
And this is the formula which can be used to compute the series:
$$S=\frac{1-3^{n+2}}{1-3^2}=\frac{3^{n+2}-1}{8}$$
Then I want to compute $S \mod 1000000007$. But if $n$ is a large number, it's really hard for me to compute it. The only thing I know is $3^{n+2}-1$ divisible by 8 (n is an even number). Could anyone give me some good hint to solve this problem?

**Update**
My intention is computing $$M=\frac{3^{n+2}-1}{8} \mod 1000000007$$
For example: If $n=4000$ I must split $3^{4000+2}$ into $3^{40}3^{40}...3^{40}3^2$ and compute modulo for each part to improve speed like this:
$$(3^{40}\mod 1000000007)(3^{40}\mod 1000000007)...(3^{40}\mod 1000000007)3^2$$
But how can I compute M with the above idea.

**Update more**
It seems related to inverse modulo. I think the problem was solved like this
$$I=\frac{(1000000007+1)}{8}=125000001$$
$$\frac{3^{n+2}-1}{8} \mod 1000000007=(3^{n+2}I-I)\mod 1000000007$$
Is it right?

Comment: You may find something helpful in this earlier question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26722/calculating-ab-mod-c

Comment: So, did you look at the link I gave? Questions about raising numbers to powers in modular arithmetic have been asked and answered repeatedly on this site --- it pays to see what's been written before.

Comment: It is true that $8I\equiv1\pmod p$ (where $p=100\dots007$), so it's true that $(3^{n+2}-1)/8\equiv3^{n+2}I-I\pmod p$. I'm not sure how much that helps you. But **did you look at the link I gave?**

Comment: Yes, I found some useful things from the link, thanks.

Comment: So, the link tells you how to calculate powers in modular arithmetic. So what is it that you still have a question about?

Answer (score 4):

The modulo value of a geometric sum

```
1 + a + a^2 + ... +a^n mod m
```

can be calculated based on the identity (if the highest exponent is odd)

```
1 + a + a^2 + ... +a^(2x+1) = (1 + a)(1 + a^2 + (a^2)^2 + ... + (a^2)^x)
```

A complete algorithm which can deal with odd *and* even highest exponents looks like this in Mathematica:

```
geometricSeriesMod[a_, n_, m_] := 
   Module[ {q = a, exp = n, factor = 1, sum = 0, temp},

   While[And[exp > 0, q != 0],
     If[EvenQ[exp],
       temp = Mod[factor*PowerMod[q, exp, m], m];
       sum = Mod[sum + temp, m];
       exp--];
     factor = Mod[Mod[1 + q, m]*factor, m];
     q = Mod[q*q, m];
     exp = Floor[ exp /2];
   ];

   Return [Mod[sum + factor, m]]
]
```

Parameters:

- `a` is the "ratio" of the series. It can be any integer (including zero and negative values).
- `n` is the highest exponent of the series. Allowed are integers >= 0.
- `m`is the integer modulus != 0

Note: The algorithm performs a Mod operation after *every* arithmetic operation. This is essential, if you transcribe this algorithm to a language with a limited word length for integers.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $n$ needs to be **even** for the formula to hold.

Hint for the first part: 
Let $S=1+3^2+3^4+...+3^n$. What is $3^2 \cdot S$? Can you find $S-3^2S$?

For the second part, do you know what $n$ is, or do you need a general formula? Are you familiar with the Euler Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The modulo value of a geometric sum

1 + a + a^2 + ... +a^n mod m

for n=6;

(1 + a^2+ (a^2)^2) + a((1 + a^2+ (a^2)^2))

for n is odd

1 + a(1 + a + a^2 + ... +a^(n-1))

A complete algorithm which can deal with odd and even highest exponents looks with O(log(n))like this:

```
typedef long long ll;

ll bigSsum(ll a, ll b,ll m)
{
        if(b==0) return 0;
        ll sum;
        if(b&1){
               sum =bigSsum( (a%m * a%m)%m, ( b-1  )/2, m  );
               sum = ( sum + (( a%m  )*( sum  ) )%m )%m;
               sum = ( 1 + ( ( a%m  )*sum  )%m  )%m;
        }
        else{
               sum = bigSsum( (a%m * a%m)%m,b/2, m  );
               sum = ( sum + ( ( a%m  )*( sum  )  )%m  )%m;
        }
     return sum%m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate
$$M=\frac{3^{4000+2}-1}{8} \mod 1000000007$$
First find $$a = 8^{-1} \mod 1000000007 = 125000001$$
and
$$b = 3^{4002} \mod 1000000007 = 417856696$$
then you have
$$M=(b-1)*a \mod 1000000007 = 927232093$$
Wikipedia has great articles on [computing the modular inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Computation) and [Modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) . These methods take $O(log(m)^2)$ time and $O(log(n)^2)$ time to compute respectively, where you have used $m=1000000007$ and $n=4000$.
In Mathematica, these methods are already built in and you can find the answer with:

```
Mod[(PowerMod[3, 4000 + 2, 1000000007] - 1)*ModularInverse[8,1000000007], 1000000007]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the property of modulus,i.e., $$(a+b)\%m = (a\%m+b\%m)\%m$$

So to calculate 
$$S=1+3+3^2+3^3+...$$

you can use

$$S\%M = (1\%M + 3\%M +3^2\%M +......)\%M$$

This will speed the process and even save you from integer overflow.